# What exactly is missing in my tests for istanbul to complain about missing branch coverage?

Tags: angular, typescript, istanbul

For the life of me, I can't figure out what istanbul is complaining about here.  I've got one branch that is uncovered in this file.  Here is the relevant part of the component in question (I stripped out unrelated bits to avoid noise):

```
export class TextComponent {
    value: string;
    _field: FieldModel;
    private _record: any;

    @Input()
    set field(field: FieldModel) {
        this._field = field;
        this.cacheValue();
    }

    @Input()
    set record(record: any) {
        this._record = record;
        this.cacheValue();
    }

    cacheValue() {
        this.value = this.getValue();
    }

    getValue(): string {
        if (!this._record || !this._field) {
            return '';
        }

        return this._field.name in this._record ? this._record[this._field.name] : '';
    }
}
```

And a sample test:

```
    it('should store the record value', () => {
        component.record = {
            first: "Nancy",
            last: "Sue",
        };
        expect(component.value).toBe('');

        component.field = {name: 'first'};
        expect(component.value).toBe('Nancy');
    });
```

My code coverage is 100% except one missing branch.  This is what the code coverage report shows:

[image]

I know for certain that the little yellow highlight is the branch that istanbul doesn't think is covered.  However, I have no idea what it is actually complaining about and therefore I don't know how to write a test to cover it.  The sample test I included is the main test that I have on this function.  Obviously it is deficient in some way, but I don't understand in what way, and that little highlight isn't very informative.

Angular 7.1.0, typescript 3.1.6

Comment: What version of Angular are you running? I vaguely remember there being a bug with coverage in an earlier version.

Comment: @MMansour I'll put that in the question - Angular 7.1.0

Comment: When I ran that class and that test I didn't get highlight in the same place as you. Instead it was on this line `return this._field.name in this._record ? this._record[this._field.name] : '';` on the else part of the ternary. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: @MMansour strange... maybe it is just an issue with istanbul.  I'm a bit new to the code coverage, so I just assumed it was something I'm doing wrong.  I have separate tests to cover that particular branch, I just didn't include them for the sake of keeping the example simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is an [open issue for istanbul](https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/issues/70). It seems like using another class in this way can cause some issues. One potential fix in this thread is to specify a return type like `any` for the method. Its likely the issue is in the javascript that TS gets translated into. The javascript likely has a branch where your code does not.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that might indeed be the case... a bit obnoxious, but I don't have my code coverage requirements set to 100%, so I'll just ignore for now...